# PHP Get Content from URL and Display

Tags: php, hyperlink, get

I have a list of links that are on the footer of my Wordpress site. I change these every day on every single site, but I have 12 sites and it is tedious. They all use the same code.

I am interested in using PHP code to call to a URL that will have the code to display in the footer section. The URL that it calls to will have everything and all it will need to do is put the code it gets from the URL (example.com/code.txt) into the footer.

Any idea on how to do this? Thank you. :)

Comment: You could use `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

try this .

`<?php echo site_url(); ?>`

or

`<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>`